# Currently visible columns in a wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid with more than 15 columns and a horizontal scroll bar is visible.How can I check whether a datagrid column is currently visible on screen or not in wpf.

Comment: can you share some code , or explain your question a little bit more ?

Comment: I have a datagrid with 19 columns.At a time only 5 or 6 columns are displayed on the screen,other columns can be displayed by scrolling the horizontal scroll bar.Moreover the width of the columns are adjustable. I want to restrict scrolling between first and last column.I used FrozenColumnCount property to freeze first column. But unable to freeze the last column.So I am trying to freeze the last column by customization.For that I want to get how many columns are currently displayed on the screen. Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work:

```
public static bool IsVisibleInView(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
  if (!element.IsVisible) return false;
  var bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0,
    element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
  var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
  return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}

public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
  System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(IsVisibleInView(grid.Columns.Last().GetCellContent(row),
    grid) ? "Visible" : "Invisible");
}
```

At least it gives you a way of checking if a certain column is presented or not. You'll have to adapt it to your specific case.